# Grid spacing is not what it should be

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I have a map of Ireland and I want to create a 10km x 10km grid over the whole country. I used the 'create grid' feature from the toolbox and put 10km as my horizontal and vertical spacing. However, when I insert a scale bar it shows me that the grid boxes are not 10km apart but are closer to 6.25km apart. (see pic 1)

The CRS I used for creating the grid is EPSG:3857 - WGS 84/ Psuedo-Mercator.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can make a grid that is actually 10km x 10km?

I have also noticed that when I change the scale bar units to 'map units' suddenly 10 grid squares do fit within 100000 units (see pic 2)
[image: Image shows how scale and grid boxes do not agree with each other. Each grid box should be 10km x 10km]

[image: when the scale bar units are changed to 'map units' the grid squares do line up with the scale bar]

Comment: Please state, which CRS you're using when creating the grid. Could you also attach a screenshot?

Comment: I'm using EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Psuedo-Mercator

Comment: So, you're talking about discrepancies between the scale bar in the print composer and your grid, not between your grid and the measurement tool.

Comment: Yes I think so, but surely the scale bar must be correct in its measurement anyway

Comment: Yeah, but the scale bar has way more options to be used wrongly than the measurement tool. I guess the grid is as intended, when you use the measurement tool?

Comment: Don't measure things in Web Mercator the answer will be wrong

Comment: Web Mercator is always wrong, but it's profoundly wrong in high latitudes (*very* inappropriate for Ireland)

Comment: For Ireland you should use Irish Transverse Mercator (ITM), EPSG: 2157

Comment: Actually I didn't realise it, but yes the measurement tool does show the correct measurement. It's just the scale bar that's wrong.